# renaming a fat16 volume

Tags: linux, partitioning, fat16, logical-drive

What's the easiest way to rename (change the volume label of) a fat16 volume (e.g. on a USB drive) from linux?  It seems like `mlabel` from the `mtools` package is meant to do this, but the documentation is not geared to rapid assimilation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found [this guide](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RenameUSBDrive#FAT16%20and%20FAT32) to using mtools, which explains the following:

---

### Check the current label

```
sudo mlabel -i <device> -s ::
```

eg:

```
sudo mlabel -i /dev/sdb1 -s ::
```

Note that we're using the special "::" drive which allows us to specify the device descriptor on the command line; otherwise we'd have to edit ~/.mtoolsrc to assign a drive letter (see Option 2 under "Change the label").

### Change the label

After unmounting and checking the current label (above), use

```
sudo mlabel -i <device> ::<label>
```

eg:

```
sudo mlabel -i /dev/sdb1 ::my_external
```

Ignore the "Volume label is XYZ" output as this is the old label. Jump to the Verify the Change section below.

---

My initial confusion stemmed from the fact that the `-i` option is not documented in the `mlabel` manpage.  The [full version](http://www.gnu.org/software/mtools/manual/mtools.html#SEC57) of the manual doesn't mention this option specifically for `mlabel`; I'm guessing it's a general option that applies to all of the `mtools` utils, but haven't dug around in the manual to check for the existence of documentation to that effect.

However, I'm finding that setting a 10-character volume label ("KATAROWSKI") doesn't work: there is some extra stuff appended to the end of the label that translates, under linux to the `à` character, and under Windows showed up as a `?`.