# Renaming a volume under Linux

Tags: linux, partitioning, formatting

It may be a very basic question, but I have USB devices that keep their old name after reformating it with `mkfs` and even after a repartitioning with `fdisk`.

I wonder if there is a way to change the disk label with simple basic tools (note that, I do not want to use the `mtools` as answered [here](https://superuser.com/questions/223527/renaming-a-fat16-volume)).

Comment: I am a bit surprised after a short web browsing, because I found pages claiming that the volume naming depends on the file system installed on it. But, I had reformated several volumes, changed from one fs to another and the label is still here. So, my guess is that it is located in the MBR and do not depends on the file system... Am I wrong ?

Answer (score 11):

It is depends on which file system is in the partition.

If the fs is ext2/ext3/ext4, `e2label` should work:

```
e2label  /dev/sda5 my_label
```

If that is NTFS, choose `ntfslabel`:

```
ntfslabel  /dev/sda9  my_label
```

If that is FAT, choose `mtools` that is what you already got:

```
mlabel -i /dev/sda4 ::my_label
```

Comment: Is there a way to tag directly the /dev/sda ? My problem is that I have a persistent tag that survive even after deleting and creating new partitions.

Comment: I once had a USB drive that I wrote an iso image to and even recreating the partition table didn't reset the name, so I used dd to overwrite the whole drive with zeros (dd bs=1M if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sdX) and recreated the partition table.

Answer (score 1):

If the name you're seeing is descriptive (such as "20GB volume"), it might be something that your file manager is creating *in the absence of* a true filesystem label. The name is "persistent" only because the file manager is generating the same description when you create a new filesystem without a name. If that's the case, then renaming the filesystem with any of the commands that Hans Chen has mentioned, or with GParted, should do the trick.

The [MBR Partitioning system](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_boot_record) does not support partition labels; however, the [GPT system](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GUID_Partition_Table) does. To the best of my knowledge, no Linux file browsers display GPT partition labels, though. If you want to edit them, you can use the [GPT fdisk (`gdisk`)](http://www.rodsbooks.com/gdisk/) tool -- but you should *not* use `gdisk` on MBR disks, since it will convert them to GPT form, which will render a disk unbootable until you re-install your boot loader. (`gdisk` warns you and gives you the chance to abort when you launch it on an MBR disk, so just stay alert to such a warning.)